# Error 1006 while sending message from server [C#] to client [HTML5 websocket]

Tags: c#, html, websocket

I've got a Big problem.
I'm trying to establish a connection between c# socket and HTML5 WebSocket

Server Code

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text;

namespace Server_CSharp_HTML5
{
    class Program
    {
        static Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
        static private string guid = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8080));
            serverSocket.Listen(128);
            serverSocket.BeginAccept(null, 0, OnAccept, null);            
            Console.Read();
        }

        private static void OnAccept(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            try
            {
                Socket client = null;
                string headerResponse = "";
                string testMessage = "Hello World!";
                if (serverSocket != null && serverSocket.IsBound)
                {
                    client = serverSocket.EndAccept(result);
                    var i = client.Receive(buffer);
                    headerResponse = (System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer)).Substring(0,i);
                    // write received data to the console
                    Console.WriteLine(headerResponse);

                }
                if (client != null)
                {
                    /* Handshaking and managing ClientSocket */

                    var key = headerResponse.Replace("ey:", "`")
                              .Split('`')[1]                    
                              .Replace("\r", "").Split('\n')[0]  
                              .Trim();

                    var test1 = AcceptKey(ref key);

                    var newLine = "\r\n";

                    var response = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols" + newLine
                         + "Upgrade: websocket" + newLine
                         + "Connection: Upgrade" + newLine
                         + "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + test1 + newLine + newLine
                         //+ "Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat, superchat" + newLine
                         //+ "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13" + newLine
                         ;
                    client.Send(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response));

                    var i = client.Receive(buffer); // wait for client to send a message

                    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(buffer).Substring(0, i));
                    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(Convert.ToBase64String(buffer).Substring(0, i)));
                    Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
                    Send(client, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(testMessage), 0, (testMessage).Length , 10000);



                }
            }
            catch (SocketException exception)
            {
                throw exception;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (serverSocket != null && serverSocket.IsBound)
                {
                    serverSocket.BeginAccept(null, 0, OnAccept, null);
                }
            }
        }

        private static string AcceptKey(ref string key)
        {
            string longKey = key + guid;
            byte[] hashBytes = ComputeHash(longKey);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);
        }

        static SHA1 sha1 = SHA1CryptoServiceProvider.Create();
        private static byte[] ComputeHash(string str)
        {
            return sha1.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str));
        }

        public static void Send(Socket socket, byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, int timeout)
        {
            int startTickCount = Environment.TickCount;
            int sent = 0;  // how many bytes is already sent
            do
            {
                if (Environment.TickCount > startTickCount + timeout)
                    throw new Exception("Timeout.");
                try
                {
                    sent += socket.Send(buffer, offset + sent, size - sent, SocketFlags.None);
                }
                catch (SocketException ex)
                {
                    if (ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.WouldBlock ||
                        ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.IOPending ||
                        ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.NoBufferSpaceAvailable)
                    {
                        // socket buffer is probably full, wait and try again
                        Thread.Sleep(30);
                    }
                    else
                        throw ex;  // any serious error occurr
                }
            } while (sent < size);
        }

    }
}
```

When I try to send a message `string testMessage = "Hello World!";`
the client give me error, the error code given is 1006.
I've searched through StackOverFlow and some forums but I can't find what i need.
Hope that someone can help me.

Regards, 50Special